# Python Watchdog script does not detect files created using a Power Automate Flow

Tags: python, python-3.x, power-automate, python-watchdog

I am having an issue where I have a Power Automate (Cloud) flow that automatically saves e-mail attachments in a specific folder and a Python Watchdog script watching that folder. However, the script does not trigger when files are added from the flow, only if I add them manually.
Everything otherwise working.

I have tried it with both `on_creation` and `on_any_event` conditions but it does not seem to work.
I wanted the script to trigger automatically when the files were added using PA.

```
import os
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
import subprocess

class NewFileHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_any_event(self, event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return
        # Replace with the path to your script
        script_path = r"path"
        subprocess.run(["python", script_path])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder_to_watch = r"path"
    event_handler = NewFileHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path=folder_to_watch, recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```